# jquery-mobile phonegap first page of app must be index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

Does the first page that shows up when an app starts have to be index.html? or can i change it to something else(othername.html)?

If it has to be index.html, can i lead the client to 
otherpage.html to make it look like it's the first page they see?

Comment: Why the restriction? This is something handled by your server's configuration, not to mention the naming convention is pretty standard.

Comment: i found the way to change it in config.xml.. should have looked in there first

Comment: @esqew -- PhoneGap apps aren't server-side web apps; they're mobile packaged hybrid apps, and there's a configuration file for things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PhoneGap application can be set up to start from any file within the app.

By default, it uses index.html, as you see, but you can set it to any other file by editing your `config.xml` file.

Look for the line that reads

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

and change it to point to your other file instead. (If there isn't a line like that in `config.xml`, then you can add one.)

Check out the configuration docs here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html